# How TO Save State in Flutter Locally

Tags: flutter, dart

how to save state in flutter am trying to make a quantity number which is displayed in text widge there is plus and minus button once I go back from the page the quantity becomes zero even though i have made it any other number

Answer (score 1):

Since your use case is simple , `it only requires storing the requisite data to JSON or UTF-8 and writing this data to an editable File.`

1.***Saving data as JSON***
The  [dart:convert library](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more)  has converters for JSON and UTF-8, as well as support for creating additional converters. JSON is a simple text format for representing structured objects and collections. UTF-8 is a common variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set.

2.***Creating and saving to an editable File***
The [I/O library](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more)  enables command-line apps to read and write files and browse directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the provider package in Flutter to manage your application state.
Here is the link to the provider package and it's documentation.

[Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

[Provider Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/)

Comment: am able to change the value but when I close the app and open it again or if I go to another screen the value is lost I have used the set state to change the state

Comment: Yes, that would happen because you are not saving the data locally. When you close the app. All the data goes away.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions on StackOverflow, it's generally preferred to share some code that you have tried.

In your case, it's likely that you need to use `setState` in your widget somewhere to modify the value of a variable in your widget class. But without seeing your code, it will be difficult to answer completely.